# Why does KL divergence show up in the proof of Hoeffding's inequality?

Tags: estimation, probability-inequalities

In some textbook the KL divergence shows up in the proof of Hoeffding's inequality (e.g., eq. (5) of [this material](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~htlin/course/ml12fall/doc/hw0_5_e.pdf)). In contrary, most other textbooks seem not mention this fact. I know that KL divergence is essentially Bregman divergence, i.e., the difference between the true value of a convex function and tis locally linear approximation. But I have no idea why there is a place for KL divergence in Hoeffding's inequality? Any intuitively explanations?

Answer (score 1):

I found answer [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr08/cos511/scribe_notes/0227.pdf). Basically, the "good looking" version of Hoeffding bound uses the inequality $D(p\| q) \ge (p-q)^2$ to "trim" the upper bound. One should keep in mind that $D(p\| q)$ is actually tighter although "bad looking".